# OpenGL reading back buffer quickly

Tags: c++, opengl, hook

I'm trying to read the contents of the back-buffer into a buffer of my own. `glReadPixels` by itself is way too slow and drops my FPS from 50 to 30.

So I decided to try the "asynchronous" read with a PBuffer but it crashes.

My code is as follows:

If buffers don't exist, create them. Otherwise, read the back buffer into a specified memory location:

```
static int readIndex = 0;
static int writeIndex = 1;
static GLuint pbo[2] = {0};


void FastCaptureBackBuffer()
{
    //Create PBOs:
    if (!initBuffers)
    {
        initBuffers = true;
        glGenBuffers(2, pbo);
        glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo[0]);
        glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, width * height * 1.0f, 0, GL_STREAM_READ);

        glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo[1]);
        glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, width * height * 1.0f, 0, GL_STREAM_READ);
        glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0);
    }

    //swap read and write.
    writeIndex = (writeIndex + 1) % 2;
    readIndex = (writeIndex + 1) % 2;

    //read back-buffer.
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo[writeIndex]);
    glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo[readIndex]);

    void* data = glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, GL_READ_ONLY);

    if (data)
    {
        memcpy(myBuffer, data, width * height * 4);
        data = nullptr;
        glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER);
    }

    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

Then I do:

```
BOOL __stdcall HookSwapBuffers(HDC DC)
{
    FastCaptureBackBufferPBO();

    return CallFunction<BOOL>(GetOriginalAddress(353), DC);
}
```

So every time the application calls `wglSwapBuffers`, I read the back buffer right before it gets swapped.

How can I read the back buffer fast? What am I missing in the above?

Ideally I wanted to: Specify a pointer that the game could render directly to, instead of the screen, and then I can manually render the contents of the memory.

Any other way and I end up copying the back buffer into my memory block and it's slow.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just FYI: PBuffers are something very different than Pixel Buffer Objects. A PBuffer is a special kind of off-screen drawable (kind of a window that can not be made visible). PBuffers were used for off-screen rendering before there were Framebuffer Objects (FBOs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not reserving enough memory in the buffer:

```
glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, width * height * 1.0f, 0, GL_STREAM_READ);
```

Since you're using `GL_RGBA` as the format, you will need 4 bytes per pixel, which also matches what you're using in your `memcpy()` call:

```
memcpy(myBuffer, data, width * height * 4);
```

So the `glBufferData()` call should be:

```
glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, width * height * 4, 0, GL_STREAM_READ);
```

Also, it's not entirely clear from your question why you're using `HookSwapBuffers()`. I believe people use that to intercept the `SwapBuffers()` call if they do not have source code. If you want to capture rendering you do yourself in your own code, you can simply call `glReadPixels()` immediately after you finished rendering the frame. It will be executed in sequence with all the other OpenGL calls, so it will contain the result of all the draw calls you issued.

Minor terminology point: What you're asking about here is not called "PBuffer". The full name is "Pixel Buffer Object", often used in its short form "PBO". A PBuffer is something quite different. It was an old mechanism for off-screen rendering that is thankfully mostly obsolete these days.

Answer (score -1):

> Any ideas?

How about you don't abuse the main framebuffer for something you should not do (rendering to a window framebuffer and read from that) and instead use a Framebuffer Object and a renderbuffer to render to. You'd still have to use glReadPixels, but since you're using an off-screen surface you're avoiding all that synchronization with the windowing system. Using a PBO for data transfer is still recommendable, since it gives the OpenGL implementation more freedom in scheduling operations. I suggest the following:

1. Render to FBO renderbuffer
2. glReadPixels from renderbuffer into a GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER PBO
3. Blit the renderbuffer to the main framebuffer
4. SwapBuffers
5. retrieve the data from the PBO

This arrangement and order of operations gives the OpenGL implementation enough leeway to asynchronously overlap some of the operations happening there without imposing some stalling synchronization points. For example the glReadPixels and blitting the renderbuffer to the main framebuffer are not interfering with each other (both only read from the renderbuffer). The OpenGL driver may rearrange for the glReadPixels to actually be executed after the blit, or at the same time. You may actually swap 2 and 3, and on some implementations this might yield better performance. Heck you could move 2 even after 4, but then you'd loose some operation reordering freedom.